# Como detener una cancion antes de comenzar otra?

Tags: c#

podrian ayudarme?
He estado investigando y no encuentro solucion.

Estoy trabajando en C#.
Tengo un botón llamado Play que ejecuta este codigo

```
        //esto va hasta arriba donde estan los demas using
        using WMPLib;

         //esto se ejecuta al presionar un boton
        try
        {
             wplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer
            {
                URL = rutaCancion //variable global tipo string
            };

            wplayer.controls.play();

        }

        catch (Exception exe)
        {

        }
```

rutaCancion contiene la ruta de la cancion. 
Al presionar el botón play, se ejecuta la cancion, el problema es que cuando selecciono otra ruta, y presiono play, la cancion anterior no deja de reproducirse, sino que continúa reproduciendose y comienza la otra cancion (se reproducen al mismo tiempo).

Como detengo la cancion anterior? he probado colocarle este codigo

```
            wplayer.controls.stop();
```

antes de darle play pero no ya no reproduce nada.

Comment: que tipo de archivo estas reproduciendo? porque quizas hay mejores librerias que la de  WindowsMediaPlayer

Comment: solo estoy reproduciendo archivos .mp3

Answer (score 0):

Si la idea es reproducir audio mp3 podrias evaluar mejores librerias como ser

[NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

puedes agregar la referencia por medio de `nuget`, analiza el ejemplo

[Play an Audio File from a WinForms application](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/PlayAudioFileWinForms.md)

En el ejemplo hace uso de `AudioFileReader` para acceder al archivo de audio.

Por supuesto no es la unica libreria podrias evaluar tambien

[cscore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore)